# Migrating Drupal 6.8 to new server causing errors and nothing else comes up

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm no good at Drupal and am trying to simply migrate a Drupal 6.8 site to a new server/host.

I dumped the database from the old host, set up a new database on the new and imported the data into it. Then moved all the files over, double checked permissions and changed the DB info in the settings file. Got a bunch of errors (more in a bit).

I also did the exact same thing on my local MAMP setup and the site came up without a problem.

So on the new host I'm getting these errors (altered the real server path just to be safe):

`Warning: Table 'nwreloc_drupal.nwreloc_access' doesn't exist query: SELECT 1 FROM nwreloc_access WHERE type = 'host' AND LOWER('71.237.232.221') LIKE LOWER(mask) AND status = 0 LIMIT 0, 1 in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 128`

Warning: Table 'nwreloc_drupal.nwreloc_users' doesn't exist query: SELECT u.*, s.* FROM nwreloc_users u INNER JOIN nwreloc_sessions s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = '9bvlnfohspprnjrhoah46o83e7' in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 128

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc:128) in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1009

Warning: Table 'nwreloc_drupal.nwreloc_cache' doesn't exist query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM nwreloc_cache WHERE cid = 'variables' in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 128

Warning: Table 'nwreloc_drupal.nwreloc_variable' doesn't exist query: SELECT * FROM nwreloc_variable in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 128

Warning: Table 'nwreloc_drupal.nwreloc_cache' doesn't exist query: UPDATE nwreloc_cache SET data = '', created = 1297381191, expire = 0, headers = '', serialized = 0 WHERE cid = 'variables' in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 128

Warning: Table 'nwreloc_drupal.nwreloc_system' doesn't exist query: SELECT name, filename, throttle FROM nwreloc_system WHERE type = 'module' AND status = 1 AND bootstrap = 1 ORDER BY weight ASC, filename ASC in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 128

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc:128) in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 610

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc:128) in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 611

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc:128) in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 612

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc:128) in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 613

Warning: Table 'nwreloc_drupal.nwreloc_url_alias' doesn't exist query: SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM nwreloc_url_alias in /my/path/to/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 128

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Never mind! Found my issue. Wrong $db_prefix. D'oh!!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [backup/migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) to do my migrations. It's smart enough to leave out all the cache tables and it means I don't need to go through the shell or use some SQL client to populate your database (though you'll still need to create the schema and users of course).

Also, you should update your Drupal version, as I'm sure there would've been several security releases since 6.8. And if this is for production then you should configure php so that errors should only go to the log (IMHO a good idea in any case).

Comment: Just saw your reply - still need to really learn Drupal so your info will come in handy. Thanks!!